# Flutter Gitlab CI CD implementation for iOS build profile not found error

Tags: ios, flutter, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, flutter-test

**Currently i am trying to implement CI for generate iOS and Android builds. for me Android Build generated successfully but when  starts build iOS build it gives following error :**

```
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                            3.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /tmp/flutter_tools.LGxyvf/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirMvl2ik/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    error: No profiles for 'com.example.cicddemo' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example.cicddemo'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /tmp/flutter_tools.LGxyvf/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirMvl2ik/temporary_xcresult_bundle
It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier.
Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
Encountered error while building for device.
```

So how we can import profiles and generate build for iOS using Gitlab CI

Answer (score 0):

It is said that no provisioning profiles matching is enabled. If you are using Fastlane for deployment you must activate matching process. That means uploading provisioning profiles files to a repository. Then giving access permission by SSH to your main project to reach that repository.Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/)